# How to listen for specific elements to load?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, event-bubbling

Is it possible to listen for a specific DOM element to be loaded? I have a `window.onload` event that is called when the whole page loads, but I'm looking for a way for it to be called for each DOM element that gets loaded. (Does `onload` not bubble up?)

Example:

```js
function init() {
  alert(this.id); // Should be in context of DOM element that bubbled up when loaded
}
window.onload = init;
```

```html
<div id="one">One</div>
<div id="two">One</div>
<div id="three">One</div>
```

I want this code to alert one, two, three.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onload` events don't bubble like this, you have 2 options here:

1. poll for the element, running a check for it on an interval.
2. use [DOM mutation events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Common.2FW3C_events) (which vary across browsers - mainly IE implementation headaches) to listen, though this will be expensive, since you'll have to filter everything *other* than your element.